# How to change access control list of performance counter?

Tags: powershell, acl, windows-server, perfmon

I could get performance counters on my server as administrator:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> Get-Counter '\memory\available bytes'

Timestamp                 CounterSamples                                                                                      
---------                 --------------                                                                                      
28.04.2014 5:19:55        \\vm108838-2\memory\available bytes :                                                               
                          393011200
```

But when I try to get performance counter from non-admin user, I get following error:

```
PS C:\Users\lpu3\Documents> Get-Counter '\memory\available bytes'
Get-Counter : Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is offline.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

[Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx) states:

> Performance counters are often protected by access control lists (ACLs). To get all available performance counters, open Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.

So, the question is, where I could change that ACL to include my user?

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the ACL. Add the user account to [a group that has permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154.aspx) to use the Performance monitor logs. As per the documentation:

```
Members of the Performance Monitor Users group 
• Can use all the features that are available to the Users group.
• Can view real-time performance data in Performance Monitor, and can change the Performance Monitor display properties while viewing real-time data. 
• Cannot create or modify Data Collector Sets.


Members of the Performance Log Users group
• Can use all the features that are available to the Performance Monitor Users group.
• Can create and modify Data Collector Sets after the group is assigned the Log on as a batch user user right, as described in Enable Logging for Performance Log Users Group Members.
• Cannot use the Windows Kernel Trace provider in Data Collector Sets.
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like this is not enought because this did not help.